Constructing nomogram from approximate model in Regression Modelling Strategies
In section 19.5 in Regression Modelling Strategies by Frank Harrell we make an approximate model using linear regression with ols. Since this is an ols object we have to calculate survival quantities manually to make a nomogram.
In the 2nd edition of the book on page 472 (491 in pdf version), the value 0.802352037606488 appears twice in this calculation. Where does this value come from? It is mentioned nowhere else in the book. The specific code is attached, where f is the full model.
expected.surv <- Mean(f)
quantile.surv <- Quantile(f)
expected.surv <- function(lp = NULL, parms = 0.802352037606488) {
  names (parms) <- NULL
  exp(lp + exp(2 * parms)/2)
}

quantile.surv <- function(q = 0.5, lp = NULL,
  parms = 0.802352037606488) {
  names (parms ) <- NULL
  f <- function(lp, q, parms) lp + exp(parms) * qnorm(q)
  names(q) <- format (q)
  drop(exp(outer (lp, q, FUN = f, parms = parms )))
}
median.surv <- function(x) quantile.surv(lp=x)


The only somewhat related example I could find in the documentation is from the function transace, which has the following example
## Not run: 
# Another example, on hypothetical data
f <- areg.boot(response ~ I(age) + monotone(blood.pressure) + race)
# use I(response) to not transform the response variable
plot(f, conf.int=.9)
# Check distribution of residuals
plot(fitted(f), resid(f))
qqnorm(resid(f))
# Refit this model using ols so that we can draw a nomogram of it.
# The nomogram will show the linear predictor, median, mean.
# The last two are smearing estimators.
Function(f, type='individual')  # create transformation functions
f.ols <- ols(.response(response) ~ age + 
             .blood.pressure(blood.pressure) + .race(race))
# Note: This model is almost exactly the same as f but there
# will be very small differences due to interpolation of
# transformations
meanr <- Mean(f) # create function of lp computing mean response
medr  <- Quantile(f)  # default quantile is .5
nomogram(f.ols, fun=list(Mean=meanr,Median=medr))

but here they don't do any transformation.
Edit:
Seems like the package got updated, so the (correct) transformation now happens by default using Mean() and Quantile(). I assume this works correctly for any model, for example also a Cox proportional hazards model?

Which edition are you looking at? ... Oh, actually,  I guess it's second edition.

Yes sorry, it's the second edition. The website version has the same value appearing, but already on expected.surv and quantile.surv. Seems like the functions got updated? I assume it then also works correctly if my full model was something else, for example, if it were a Cox proportional hazards model?
hbiostat.org/rmsc/psmcase

To my inderstanding there are different constants for different models. That one was for a lognormal parametric survival  model
